# Is pad.ubuntu.com available for everyone?

Tags: community, uds, ubuntu-website

I really love the interface at http://pad.ubuntu.com . It seems to be a great notepad when you want to do notes with other people.

However, the main page says 'Ubuntu Developer Summit'. Does it mean it's meant to be used exclusively for UDS? If not, can I use it with my friends, would it be awkward?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link you posted is actually only for UDS/Ubuntu but the software used is `etherpad` and you can use it yourself on `localhost` with a browser.

Etherpad was bought by Google and they open source'd it ([More info](http://etherpad.com/)). That link has several working instances of forks of Etherpad: [Piratepad](http://piratepad.net/ZlgSZxq0cX), [Typewith.me](http://typewith.me/), [iEtherpad](http://ietherpad.com/rOzyeBBtnm). You can use these with your friends but all of these are `untrusted` and use a remote server to host your files so be careful). Random image from those links:

[image]

All the Ubuntu debs and ppas I found are really old (like from `hardy`) so if you want your own version on your own system Google supplies instructions on [compiling and running](http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/wiki/Instructions) the latest version of Etherpad. From the link:

**Requirements**

- Java 1.6 (tested with 1.6.0_10)
- Scala 2.7 (tested with 2.7.4)
- MySQL Server 5.1 (tested with 5.1.41)
- mysql-connector-java (tested with 5.1.0)

**Environment**
Various scripts make assumptions about environment variables:

- `JAVA` should be set to the java executable.
- `JAVA_HOME` should be set to the main jdk directory.
- `SCALA` should be set to the scala executable.
- `SCALA_HOME` should be set to the main scala distribution directory.
- `PATH` should contain `$JAVA`, `$SCALA`, and mysql
- `MYSQL_CONNECTOR_JAR` should be set to the mysql-connector JAR file included in the mysql-connector download.

**Database Setup**

- The scripts assume mysqld is running on localhost. Once mysqld is running, you can set up the etherpad database by running the following command inside `ajcode/etherpad/`.

  ```
  sudo bin/setup-mysql-db.sh
  ```

  This will create a database called "etherpad" with the password "password", and grant privileges to the user "etherpad". All the tables will be set up the first time etherpad is run.

**Compiling**

- EtherPad compiles all its Java and Scala libraries into a single JAR. To build this jar, you can run the following command inside `ajcode/etherpad/`.

  ```
  bin/rebuildjar.sh
  ```

  If you modify anything in `ajcode/infrastructure`, you will most likely need to kill the server, rebuild the jar, and re-launch the server before your change takes effect. Code inside `ajcode/etherpad/src` can be modified while the server is running, and the changes will automatically get picked up.

**Running**

- To run the etherpad web server, execute the following command inside ajcode/etherpad/.

  ```
  bin/run-local.sh
  ```

  The first time you run this, it should print out lots of messages about database migrations and finally print:

  ```
  HTTP server listening on http://localhost:9000/
  ```

  At this point, you should be able to visit http://localhost:9000/ in your web browser and create a new pad.

Answer (score 0):

If one actually need to use http://pad.ubuntu.com/

go and join the group at the https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-etherpad